# Best way to verify if there are at least one record on that match the query

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have to do a query for a Oracle database to verify if there are at least one record that match my query.

There are 6 joins in the tables and the main table have about 40 million records.

I try two ways to do the select:

```
select 1 from Table t ... 
    join X on x.id = T.id join Y on y.id = x.id ....
    where x.field = ? and y.field = ? and t.field = ?
    and rownum = 1
```

and

```
select count (*) from Table t ... 
    join X on x.id = T.id join Y on y.id = x.id ....
where 
    x.field = ? and y.field = ? and t.field = ?
    and rownum = 1
```

I don't have experience with Databses querys at all, in preliminars tests I get betters queries times in the first case, but when there is no records the first query seems to be very slow. But I don't know even if i'm doing the benchmark in the correctly.

So I ask, what is the best way to do this type of queries?

Comment: Please remove the commas before the JOIN keyword.

Comment: If the actual queries differ only in that one is selecting a hard-coded constant and one is doing a `count(*)`, I would expect that you'd get the same query plan for both and, thus, that performance would be identical.  Do you actually get the same plans for both statements?  Or do you get a different plan for one of the statements?

Answer (score 0):

You are using t-sql and not pl/sql. Your second query should be formed like this:

```
select count (*) 
from Table t, X, Y
where x.id = T.id and 
y.id = x.id and
x.field = ? and 
y.field = ? and 
t.field = ?
```

...and you dont really need the rownum = 1, just a count.

Comment: it might be best to do select count(t.id) t_cnt, count(x.id) x_cnt, count(y.id) y_cnt

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no differences in the two ways to doing the query.